# How to sort letters in a string?

Tags: r, sorting

Let's say I have a string `s = "bcabca"`.

What is the simplest way to get `"aabbcc"` out of it, i.e., sort the letters in `s`?

Comment: How do you define "simplest"?

Comment: Straightforward, natural, shortest :) For example, in Haskell you can say `sort "bcabca"`, and get "aabbcc". This is something I call simple :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Maybe not the most simple answer, but this will work:

```
paste(sort(unlist(strsplit(s, ""))), collapse = "")
```

Or modify the `strReverse` function that is defined in the help page for `?strsplit` to suit our needs. We'll call it strSort:

```
strSort <- function(x)
        sapply(lapply(strsplit(x, NULL), sort), paste, collapse="")
```

Comment: A variation using `stri_flatten` instead of `paste`: `stri_flatten(sort(unlist(strsplit(s,""))))`

Comment: of course the first answer fails on character _vectors_. and i suspect the second will be slower than `sapply(strsplit(x, NULL), function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = '')` (which is already slow)

Answer (score 18):

Here's a variant of Chase's solution that handles a vector of strings and keeps the original strings as names. ...and I get a chance to promote the use of vapply over sapply :-)

```
> x=c('hello', 'world', NA, 'a whole sentence')
> vapply(x, function(xi) paste(sort(strsplit(xi, NULL)[[1]]), collapse=''), '')
             hello              world               <NA>   a whole sentence 
           "ehllo"            "dlorw"                 "" "  aceeeehlnnostw"
```

Comment: Yes, never use sapply when you can use vapply!

Comment: Reading this again two years later, there's a very slight fix to this to make it work for vectors, see my edited answer (only after submitting the edit did I read your response again and see it's all but the same! convergent evolution...)

Answer (score 8):

It might be good to mention the `stringi` package for this problem.  It's `stri_order` and `stri_sort` functions are very efficient, testing at half the time of the base R method mentioned above.

```
library(stringi)
## generate 10k random strings of 100 characters each
str <- stri_rand_strings(1e4, 100)
## helper function for vapply()
striHelper <- function(x) stri_c(x[stri_order(x)], collapse = "")
## timings
system.time({
  v1 <- vapply(stri_split_boundaries(str, type = "character"), striHelper, "")
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.747   0.000   0.743 

system.time({
  v2 <- sapply(lapply(strsplit(str, NULL), sort), paste, collapse="")
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   2.077   0.000   2.068 

identical(v1, v2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: is `stringi` passing things through C to speed up?

Comment: @MichaelChirico - Yes, the package is written almost entirely in C

Comment: I'll add that for `tidyverse` users `stringr::str_order` wraps `stri_order` so you don't need to explicitly load another package when you already have `stringr` loaded by `tidyverse`.

Answer (score 4):

Revisiting this, my old answer wasn't so good. Here's a better version with `base` functions:

```
vapply(strsplit(x, NULL), function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = ''), '')
```

Based off this test vector:

```
NN = 1000000L
starts = seq(1L, NN, by = 100L)
name = 
  substring(paste(sample(letters, size = NN, replace = TRUE), collapse = ""),
            starts, starts + 99L)
```