# How to sort characters in each element of a character vector?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to sort letters in a string in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904797/how-to-sort-letters-in-a-string-in-r)

I have a dataframe where a variable is a character string. Is there a way to create another variable having the same elements as x, but each sorted in ascending or descending order as below:

> x_old: (trad, jfwd, qerf...)
>
> x_new: (adrt, dfjw, efqr...)

Comment: This is, in fact, identical: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5904797/602276

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be an easier way:

```
x <- c("trad", "jfwd", "qerf")
unname(sapply(x, function(i)paste(sort(unlist(strsplit(i, ""))), collapse="")))
[1] "adrt" "dfjw" "efqr"
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the dummy data:

```
strs <- c("trad", "jfwd", "qerf")
```

You can do this with a series of steps over the character vector:

```
sapply(                                   ## 3
       lapply(                            ## 2
              sapply(strs, strsplit, ""), ## 1
              sort),                      ## 2
       paste, collapse = "")              ## 3
```

which gives:

```
> sapply(lapply(sapply(strs, strsplit, ""), sort), paste, collapse = "")
  trad   jfwd   qerf 
"adrt" "dfjw" "efqr"
```

Where in the function, `## 1` splits each element of the character vector into single characters, `## 2` sorts these sets of characters, and `## 3` pastes them back together again.

We can do this in a single step by encapsulating the steps into a function:

```
foo <- function(x) {
    x <- strsplit(x, split = "")[[1]]
    x <- sort(x)
    paste(x, collapse = "")
}
```

which can be used as:

```
> sapply(strs, foo)
  trad   jfwd   qerf 
"adrt" "dfjw" "efqr"
```

Comment: +1 For explaining how my one-liner works!

Comment: @Andrie :-D I wonder if that will get me the Precognitive badge..?