# R: How to sum two separate values of two variables?

Tags: r

I have data 7320 obs of 3 variables: age groups and contact number between them. Ex:

```
ageGroup ageGroup1  mij
0   0   0.012093847617507
0   1   0.00510485237464309
0   2   0.00374919082969427
0   3   0.00307241431437433
0   4   0.00254487083293498
0   5   0.00213734013959765
0   6   0.00182565778959543
0   7   0.00159036659169942
1   0   0.00475097494199872
1   1   0.00748329237103462
1   2   0.00427123298868537
1   3   0.00319622224196792
1   4   0.00287522072903812
1   5   0.00257773394696414
1   6   0.00230322568677366
1   7   0.00205265986733139
```

and so on until 86. I have to calculate mean of contact number (`mij`) between `ageGroup`s so that, for example, `ageGroup` = 0 contacts with `ageGroup1` =1 with `mij` and `ageGroup` = 1 contacts with `ageGroup1` = 0 with `mij`. I need to sum this values and divide by 2 to get an average between then. Would you be so kind to give me a hint how to do that all over the data?

Comment: I am afraid the question conditions are not very clearly formulated. It would help if you provided an example output. In general, it seems you need the `ddply` function from `plyr` package.

Comment: tapply with ageGroup columns as factors and mean as the function?

Comment: A hint: search here on SO for `aggregate` `plyr` `ddply` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ddply` from plyr package (assuming your dataframe is data)

```
ddply(data,.(ageGroup,ageGroup1),summarize,sum.mij=sum(mij))

 ageGroup ageGroup1     sum.mij
1         0         0 0.012093848
2         0         1 0.005104852
3         0         2 0.003749191
4         0         3 0.003072414
5         0         4 0.002544871
6         0         5 0.002137340
7         0         6 0.001825658
8         0         7 0.001590367
9         1         0 0.004750975
10        1         1 0.007483292
11        1         2 0.004271233
12        1         3 0.003196222
13        1         4 0.002875221
14        1         5 0.002577734
15        1         6 0.002303226
16        1         7 0.002052660
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you're trying to do here.  You want to treat interactions between the two ageGroup columns as being non-directional and get the mean interaction?  The code below should do this using base R functions.

Note that since the example dataset is truncated, it will only give a correct answer for the group with index 01.  However if you run with the full dataset, it should work for all interactions.

```
# Create the data frame
df=read.table(header=T,text="
ageGroup,ageGroup1,mij
0,0,0.012093848
0,1,0.005104852
0,2,0.003749191
0,3,0.003072414
0,4,0.002544871
0,5,0.00213734
0,6,0.001825658
0,7,0.001590367
1,0,0.004750975
1,1,0.007483292
1,2,0.004271233
1,3,0.003196222
1,4,0.002875221
1,5,0.002577734
1,6,0.002303226
1,7,0.00205266
",sep=",")
df

# Using the strSort function from this SO answer: 
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904797/how-to-sort-letters-in-a-string-in-r
strSort <- function(x)
        sapply(lapply(strsplit(x, NULL), sort), paste, collapse="")

# Label each of the i-j interactions and j-i interactions with an index ij
# e.g. anything in ageGroup=1 interacting with ageGroup1=0 OR ageGroup=0 interacting with ageGroup1=1 
# are labelled with index 01 
df$ind=strSort(paste(df$ageGroup,df$ageGroup1,sep=""))

# Use the tapply function to get mean interactions for each group as suggested by Paul
tapply(df$mij,df$ind,mean)
```