# Summarize two columns given unique combinations

Tags: r

Thanks in advance. I have a data frame of trips denoting start locations, finish locations and distance between each location *combination*. Like so:

```
Start = c("Johns House", "Mikes House", "Franks House")
Finish = c("Mikes House", "Johns House", "Lisas House")
Distance = c(1000,1000,500) 
myDF = data.frame(Start, Finish, Distance)
```

I'd like to return a new data frame that deals with the two John/Mike trips but treats them as one unique combination.  Specifically, I'd like to return the count of total trips for each combination and the distance between locations - so the output would be:

```
newStart = c("Johns House", "Franks House")
newFinish = c("Mikes House", "Lisas House")
newDistance = c(1000,500)
Count = c(2,1)
newDF = data.frame(newStart, newFinish, newDistance, Count)
```

Many thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
myDT <- data.table(myDF)
x <- paste(myDT$Start, myDT$Finish, sep = "|")
myDT$v <- vapply(x, function(xi) paste(sort(strsplit(xi, "[|]")[[1]]), collapse=''), '')
myDT[, Count := length(Distance), by = v]
myDT <- myDT[!duplicated(v), ]
myDT

#          Start      Finish Distance           v Count
#1:  Johns House Mikes House     1000  JohnsMikes     2
#2: Franks House Lisas House      500 FranksLisas     1
```

I used @Tommy's answer [How to sort letters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904797/how-to-sort-letters-in-a-string-in-r) to sort the strings.

Comment: Does the string use "XYZ House" as in the example? Because I'm splitting based on that. I've updated my answer to make it a little clearer what is going on.

Comment: I just ran your code on the example and myDF remains unchanged.

Comment: Thanks Matt...I appreciate the help - but still no luck

Comment: Third times a charm? Didn't notice that you wanted counts and I had left out the pasting together of strings in my original answer.

Comment: Matt- thanks, this is really cool. I appreciate you answering the question, but I'm curious if its possible to amend it such that there is no requirement on the actual string being used. Say, instead of "House" it was "Bus Stop"

Comment: I'm no longer splitting on " House" now. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Matt - thanks a lot.  I found a second algorithm that works and in the data I'm finding a bit of a discrepancy in the number of unique trip combinations across algorithms, but your code is really quite swift and I really appreciate it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be easier with SQL. Install an SQL package in R, like "sqldf".

First you can count how many trips you have for each tuple Start - Finish in either way:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select distinct 
      min(a.Start, a.Finish) Start, 
      max(a.Start, a.Finish) Finish, 
      a.Distance, 
      count(*) Count
      from myDF a, myDF b
      where (a.Start = b.Start and  a.Finish = b.Finish)
      or (a.Start = b.Finish and a.Finish = b.Start)
      group by a.Start")

#          Start      Finish Distance Count
# 1 Franks House Lisas House      500     1
# 2  Johns House Mikes House     1000     2
```