# Creating new IDs (two-way) from two vectors

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two vectors in a data frame consisting of factors (~10000 unique factors in each).

Here's a simplified example of how my data look like:

```
tg<-data.frame(A=sample(letters[1:5],30,replace=TRUE),
               B=sample(letters[1:5],30,replace=TRUE))
   A B
1  b b
2  a b
3  e e
4  c b
5  e e
6  a b
7  d a
8  d a
9  d b
10 a e
11 a e
. . .
```

I want to combine (row-wise) the elements in both columns and create a new ID.

One way would be to simply paste both columns together:

```
paste0(tg$A,tg$B)
[1] "bb" "ab" "ee" "cb" "ee" "ab" "da" "da" "db" "ae"
"ae" "bc" "ae" "bb" "ec" "ba" "dd" "de" "cd" "eb" "cd"
"db" "dc" "ab" "ae" "cc" "dc" "ce" "eb" "ea"
```

**But** I would like to make new IDs that regard "ab" and "ba" as the same, how can I do that?

*Edit: sorry for the confusing title, I couldn't find any better way to explain the problem (hence couldn't find any solution for it - if there's one here already).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorting letters within your ID's will resolve the problem (following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904797/how-to-sort-letters-in-a-string-in-r)):

```
strSort <- function(x)
     sapply(lapply(strsplit(x, NULL), sort), paste, collapse="")
unique(sapply(new_ids, strSort))
 [1] "be" "bd" "bc" "ae" "aa" "ab" "ad" "cd" "ac" "dd" "ee" "ce" "cc" "de"
```