# R: Merging dataframe where index of multiple columns is an unordered set

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have a list of countries

```
countries <- c("MAL","CHL","URU","YPR","OMA","GUY","HON","SAL","CYP")
```

and two dataframes containing all possible dyads among the two countries

```
set.seed(28100)
df1 <- as.data.frame(t(combn(countries, 2)))
df1$year <- sample(1800:2000, 36)
df1$value1 <- sample(1:100, 36)

df2 <- as.data.frame(t(combn(rev(countries), 2)))
df2$year <- sample(1800:2000, 36)
df2$value2 <- sample(LETTERS, 36, replace = TRUE)
```

Now I want to merge the two dataframes by countries and by year (`by = c("V1","V2","year")`) without worrying about the actual order in which the pair of countries is listed. 
So the observation where `V1 == "SAL"` and `V2=="CYP"` can either merge with `V1 == "SAL"` and `V2=="CYP"` or `V2 == "SAL"` and `V1=="CYP"`.

Comment: you have to make an index column for each dataframe. i would somehow, by row, sort the V1 V2 values and concatenate them. Then merge on resulting index columns.

Comment: @RichardScriven The only idea I had was to try both combinations. Then instead of a single `merge()` , use two  `merge()`. But it's not really efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses an index column made from the V1 V2 columns of each dataframe. The index column contains sorted words of the concatentation between V1 and V2 column.

```
# `strSort` was taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904797/how-to-sort-letters-in-a-string-in-r
strSort <- function(x)
  sapply(lapply(strsplit(x, NULL), sort), paste, collapse="")

#df1
index=paste0(as.character(df1[,1]), as.character(df1[,2]))
df1$index=strSort(index)

#df2
index=paste0(as.character(df2[,1]), as.character(df2[,2]))
df2$index=strSort(index)

merge(df1,df2,by="index")
```

Partial output:

```
#     index V1.x V2.x year.x value1 V1.y V2.y year.y value2
# 1  AALLMS  MAL  SAL   1883     35  SAL  MAL   1971      Y
# 2  AALMMO  MAL  OMA   1915     75  OMA  MAL   1816      A
# 3  AALMOS  OMA  SAL   1806     95  SAL  OMA   1894      X
# 4  ACHLLM  MAL  CHL   1870     27  CHL  MAL   1991      U
# 5  ACHLLS  CHL  SAL   1949     55  SAL  CHL   1928      E
# 6  ACHLMO  CHL  OMA   1966     31  OMA  CHL   1839      X
# 7  ACLMPY  MAL  CYP   1830     15  CYP  MAL   1912      Y
# 8  ACLPSY  SAL  CYP   1881     60  CYP  SAL   1995      M
```