# Find overlapping dates for each ID and create a new row for the overlap

Tags: r, date, overlap, overlapping-matches

I would like to find the overlapping dates for each ID and create a new row with the overlapping dates and also combine the characters (char) for the lines. It is possible that my data will have >2 overlaps and need >2 combinations of characters.  eg. ERM

Data:

```
ID    date1         date2       char
15  2003-04-05  2003-05-06      E
15  2003-04-20  2003-06-20      R
16  2001-01-02  2002-03-04      M
17  2003-03-05  2007-02-22      I   
17  2005-04-15  2014-05-19      C
17  2007-05-15  2008-02-05      I
17  2008-02-05  2012-02-14      M
17  2010-06-07  2011-02-14      V
17  2010-09-22  2014-05-19      P
17  2012-02-28  2013-03-04      R
```

Output I would like:

```
ID  date1       date2           char
15  2003-04-05  2003-04-20      E
15  2003-04-20  2003-05-06      ER
15  2003-05-06  2003-06-20      R
16  2001-01-02  2002-03-04      M
17  2003-03-05  2005-04-15      I
17  2005-04-15  2007-02-22      IC
17  2005-04-15  2007-05-15      C   
17  2007-05-15  2008-02-05      CI
17  2008-02-05  2012-02-14      CM
17  2010-06-07  2011-02-14      CV
17  2010-09-22  2014-05-19      CP
17  2012-02-28  2013-03-04      CR
17  2014-05-19  2014-05-19      P
17  2010-06-07  2012-02-14      MV
17  2010-09-22  2011-02-14      VP
17  2012-02-28  2013-03-04      RP
```

What I have tried: 
I have tried using subtracting date 2 from the current row from the row below using:

```
df$diff <- c(NA,df[2:nrow(tdf), "date1"] - df[1:(nrow(df)-1), "date2"])
```

Then to determine the overlaps between the rows:

```
df$overlap[which(df$diff<1)] <-1
df$overlap.up <- c(df$overlap[2:(nrow(df))], "NA")
df$overlap.final[which(df$overlap==1 | df$overlap.up==1)] <- 1
```

I then selected those that had an overlap.final==1 and put them into another dataframe and found the overlaps for each ID.

However, I have realized that this is way too simplistic and flawed, because it only selects overlaps that occur sequentially (using the difference in dates in the first step). What I need to do is to take the series of dates for each ID and loop through each combination to determine if there is an overlap and then, if so, record that start and end date and create a new character “char” signalling what was combined during those two dates. I think I need a loop to do this.

I tried to create a loop to find the overlap intervals between date1 and date 2

```
df <- df[which(!duplicated(df$ ID)),]

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  tmp <- length(which(df $ID[i] & (df$date1[i] >df$date1 & df$date1[i]< df$date2) | (df$date2[i] < df$date2&  df$date2[i]> df$date1))) >0
  df$int[i]<- tmp

}
```

However this does not work.

After identifying the overlapping intervals, I need to create new rows for each new start and end date and a new character that represents the overlap.

Another version of the loop I have tried to identify overlaps:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (df$ID[i]==IDs$ID){
  tmp <- length(df, df$ ID[i]==IDs$ & (df$date1[i]> df$date1 & df$date1 [i]< df$date2 | df$date2[i] < df$date2 &  df$date2[i]> df$date1)) >0
  df$int[i]<- tmp
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and where do you get stuck?

Comment: The `IRanges` package on bioconductor has some nice functions for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480031/roll-join-with-start-end-window

Comment: Are your dates are of some nice time/date data format or are they strings? I mean: the basic idea is to look whether `date1[i1]>date1[i2] && date1[i1]<date2[i2]` and the same for `date2[i1]`. Then the both rows are combined. The `date1` and `date2` are set to `min` of both `date1` and `date2`, respectively. Your question to >2 overlapping intervals: ERI is such a case. Do you want four new rows (ER, EI, RI, and ERI) and one new row (ERI)? The latter might yield some conflicts. I would solve it with some recursive function call ... .

Comment: Hi @RomanLuštrik, I have edited my post to reflect what I've tried so far.

Comment: Hi @daniel.neumann, I have tried something similar to what you are suggesting to find the overlapping dates, without success, yet. Yes the dates are in "%Y-%m-%d" format. Yes, I would like to create new rows that show the dates of the overlap, plus a combination of characters (in my data they are actually words) to reflect what the overlap was.

Answer (score 12):

First, we create a `data.table` of all possible intervals for each `ID`.

*All possible intervals* means that we take all start and end dates of an `ID` and  combine them in a sorted vector `tmp`. The unique values indicate all possible *intersections* (or *breaks*) of all given intervals of the `ID` on the time axis. For later joining, the *breaks* are re-arranged in one interval per row with a `start` and an `end` column:

```
library(data.table)
options(datatable.print.class = TRUE)
breaks <- DT[, {
  tmp <- unique(sort(c(date1, date2)))
  .(start = head(tmp, -1L), end = tail(tmp, -1L))
  }, by = ID]
breaks
```

> ```
>        ID      start        end
>     <int>     <IDat>     <IDat>
>  1:    15 2003-04-05 2003-04-20
>  2:    15 2003-04-20 2003-05-06
>  3:    15 2003-05-06 2003-06-20
>  4:    16 2001-01-02 2002-03-04
>  5:    17 2003-03-05 2005-04-15
>  6:    17 2005-04-15 2007-02-22
>  7:    17 2007-02-22 2007-05-15
>  8:    17 2007-05-15 2008-02-05
>  9:    17 2008-02-05 2010-06-07
> 10:    17 2010-06-07 2010-09-22
> 11:    17 2010-09-22 2011-02-14
> 12:    17 2011-02-14 2012-02-14
> 13:    17 2012-02-14 2012-02-28
> 14:    17 2012-02-28 2013-03-04
> 15:    17 2013-03-04 2014-05-19
> ```

Then, a *non-equi join*  is performed whereby the values are aggregated simultaneously on the join conditions (`by = .EACHI` is called *grouping by each i*, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27004566/3817004) for a more detailed explanation):

```
DT[breaks, on = .(ID, date1 <= start, date2 >= end), paste(char, collapse = ""),  
   by = .EACHI, allow.cartesian = TRUE]
```

> ```
>        ID      date1      date2     V1
>     <int>     <IDat>     <IDat> <char>
>  1:    15 2003-04-05 2003-04-20      E
>  2:    15 2003-04-20 2003-05-06     ER
>  3:    15 2003-05-06 2003-06-20      R
>  4:    16 2001-01-02 2002-03-04      M
>  5:    17 2003-03-05 2005-04-15      I
>  6:    17 2005-04-15 2007-02-22     IC
>  7:    17 2007-02-22 2007-05-15      C
>  8:    17 2007-05-15 2008-02-05     CI
>  9:    17 2008-02-05 2010-06-07     CM
> 10:    17 2010-06-07 2010-09-22    CMV
> 11:    17 2010-09-22 2011-02-14   CMVP
> 12:    17 2011-02-14 2012-02-14    CMP
> 13:    17 2012-02-14 2012-02-28     CP
> 14:    17 2012-02-28 2013-03-04    CPR
> 15:    17 2013-03-04 2014-05-19     CP
> ```

The result differs from the expected result posted by the OP but plotting the data convinces that the above result shows all possible overlaps:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DT) + aes(y = char, yend = char, x = date1, xend = date2) + 
  geom_segment() + facet_wrap("ID", ncol = 1L)
```

[image]

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
  "ID    date1         date2       char
15  2003-04-05  2003-05-06      E
15  2003-04-20  2003-06-20      R
16  2001-01-02  2002-03-04      M
17  2003-03-05  2007-02-22      I   
17  2005-04-15  2014-05-19      C
17  2007-05-15  2008-02-05      I
17  2008-02-05  2012-02-14      M
17  2010-06-07  2011-02-14      V
17  2010-09-22  2014-05-19      P
17  2012-02-28  2013-03-04      R"
)
cols <- c("date1", "date2")
DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.IDate), .SDcols = cols]
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I was having trouble applying `foverlaps` in the way I wanted but this worked. I'm unfamiliar with `data.table` grammar, can I ask what `by = .EACHI` does exactly in your non-equi join? And if I were only interested in overlapping pairs / dyads, is there any way I could return just two overlapping `char` in two separate columns? Thanks!

Comment: @jogall Concerning your first question I have updated my answer with a link to a more detailed explanation. Concerning your second question I believe this can be solved as well. However, according to SO guidelines I kindly suggest that you pose a new question. Please, keep me posted. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and extra detail to your answer, that's very useful. I've posed this as a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49880546/find-the-duration-of-overlap-between-pairs-of-timestamps-using-data-table) if you think you can suggest a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Wow! I really enjoyed reading this answer. Beautiful and concise code! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## Introduction

The `for`-loop you added to your question and the included comparison were a good start. The should be some additional brackets `(` and `)` in the date comparison. This `for`-loop-approach automatically considers new rows in the data frame. Therefore, you can get three-, four- and more-character strings in the `char` column.

## Create input data

```
df = as.data.frame(list('ID'=c(15, 15, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17),
                        'date1'=as.Date(c('2003-04-05', '2003-04-20', '2001-01-02', '2003-03-05', '2005-04-15', '2007-05-15', '2008-02-05', '2010-06-07', '2010-09-22', '2012-02-28')),
                        'date2'=as.Date(c('2003-05-06', '2003-06-20', '2002-03-04', '2007-02-22', '2014-05-19', '2008-02-05', '2012-02-14', '2011-02-14', '2014-05-19', '2013-03-04')),
                        'char'=c('E', 'R', 'M', 'I', 'C', 'I', 'M', 'V', 'P', 'R')),
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

## Solution

Iterate all rows (that were existing in the original data.frame) and compare them to all current lines.

```
nrow_init = nrow(df)
for (i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)) {
  print(i)
  ## get rows of df that have overlapping dates
  ##   (1:nrow(df))>i :: consider only rows below the current row to avoid double processing of two row-pairs
  ##   (!grepl(df$char[i],df$char)) :: prevent double letters
  ## Because we call nrow(df) each time (and not save it as a variable once in the beginning), we consider also new rows here. Therefore, we do not need the specific procedure for comparing 3 or more rows.
  loc = ((1:nrow(df))>i) & (!grepl(df$char[i],df$char)) & (df$ID[i]==df$ID) & (((df$date1[i]>df$date1) & (df$date1[i]<df$date2)) | ((df$date1>df$date1[i]) & (df$date1<df$date2[i])) | ((df$date2[i]<df$date2) & (df$date2[i]>df$date1)) | ((df$date2<df$date2[i]) & (df$date2>df$date1[i])))
  ## Uncomment this line, if you want to compare only two rows each and not more
  # loc = ((1:nrow(df))<=nrow_init) & ((1:nrow(df))>i) & (df$ID[i]==df$ID) & (((df$date1[i]>df$date1) & (df$date1[i]<df$date2)) | ((df$date2[i]<df$date2) & (df$date2[i]>df$date1)))

  ## proceed only of at least one duplicate row was found
  if (sum(loc) > 0) {
    # build new rows
    #  pmax and pmin do element-wise min and max calculation; df$date1[i] and df$date2[i] are automatically extended to the length of df$date1[loc] and df$date2[loc], respectively
    df_append = as.data.frame(list('ID'=df$ID[loc],
                                   'date1'=pmax(df$date1[i],df$date1[loc]),
                                   'date2'=pmin(df$date2[i],df$date2[loc]),
                                   'char'=paste0(df$char[i],df$char[loc])))
    ## append new rows
    df = rbind(df, df_append)
  }
}

## create a new column and sort the characters in it
##  idea for sort: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5904854/4612235
df$sort_char = df$char
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) df$sort_char[i] = paste(sort(unlist(strsplit(df$sort_char[i], ""))), collapse = "")
## remove duplicates
df = df[!duplicated(df[c('ID', 'date1', 'date2', 'sort_char')]),]
## remove additional column
df$sort_char = NULL
```

## Out put

```
ID      date1      date2 char
15 2003-04-05 2003-05-06    E
15 2003-04-20 2003-06-20    R
16 2001-01-02 2002-03-04    M
17 2003-03-05 2007-02-22    I
17 2005-04-15 2014-05-19    C
17 2007-05-15 2008-02-05    I
17 2008-02-05 2012-02-14    M
17 2010-06-07 2011-02-14    V
17 2010-09-22 2014-05-19    P
17 2012-02-28 2013-03-04    R
15 2003-04-20 2003-05-06   ER
17 2005-04-15 2007-02-22   IC
17 2007-05-15 2008-02-05   CI
17 2008-02-05 2012-02-14   CM
17 2010-06-07 2011-02-14   CV
17 2010-09-22 2014-05-19   CP
17 2012-02-28 2013-03-04   CR
17 2010-06-07 2011-02-14   MV
17 2010-09-22 2012-02-14   MP
17 2010-06-07 2011-02-14  MCV
17 2010-09-22 2012-02-14  MCP
17 2010-09-22 2011-02-14   VP
17 2010-09-22 2011-02-14  VCP
17 2010-09-22 2011-02-14  VMP
17 2010-09-22 2011-02-14 VMCP
17 2012-02-28 2013-03-04   PR
17 2012-02-28 2013-03-04  PCR
```

Comment: ... there are missing some combination; I will soon post an improvement

Answer (score 1):

You can also use dplyr/tidyr along with the [ivs](https://davisvaughan.github.io/ivs/index.html) package, which is a package dedicated to working with *interval vectors* like you have here. This allows you to combine your start/end dates into a single interval column and use a variety of `iv_*()` functions on it, here we use `iv_identify_splits()`.

Understanding `iv_identify_splits()` can be a little tricky at first, so I'd encourage you to take a look at the graphical representation of that operation [here](https://davisvaughan.github.io/ivs/reference/iv-splits.html#graphical-representation)

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ivs)

df <- tribble(
  ~ID,       ~date1,       ~date2, ~char,
  15L, "2003-04-05", "2003-05-06",   "E",
  15L, "2003-04-20", "2003-06-20",   "R",
  16L, "2001-01-02", "2002-03-04",   "M",
  17L, "2003-03-05", "2007-02-22",   "I",
  17L, "2005-04-15", "2014-05-19",   "C",
  17L, "2007-05-15", "2008-02-05",   "I",
  17L, "2008-02-05", "2012-02-14",   "M",
  17L, "2010-06-07", "2011-02-14",   "V",
  17L, "2010-09-22", "2014-05-19",   "P",
  17L, "2012-02-28", "2013-03-04",   "R"
) %>%
  mutate(
    date1 = as.Date(date1),
    date2 = as.Date(date2)
  )

# Combine the start/stop endpoints into a single interval vector
df <- df %>%
  mutate(interval = iv(date1, date2), .keep = "unused")

# Note that these are half-open intervals and you may need to adjust the end!
df
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>       ID char                  interval
#>    <int> <chr>               <iv<date>>
#>  1    15 E     [2003-04-05, 2003-05-06)
#>  2    15 R     [2003-04-20, 2003-06-20)
#>  3    16 M     [2001-01-02, 2002-03-04)
#>  4    17 I     [2003-03-05, 2007-02-22)
#>  5    17 C     [2005-04-15, 2014-05-19)
#>  6    17 I     [2007-05-15, 2008-02-05)
#>  7    17 M     [2008-02-05, 2012-02-14)
#>  8    17 V     [2010-06-07, 2011-02-14)
#>  9    17 P     [2010-09-22, 2014-05-19)
#> 10    17 R     [2012-02-28, 2013-03-04)

# For each ID, compute the "splits" for each interval.
# This splits on all the endpoints and returns a list column
df <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(splits = iv_identify_splits(interval))

print(df, n = 3)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>      ID char                  interval           splits
#>   <int> <chr>               <iv<date>> <list<iv<date>>>
#> 1    15 E     [2003-04-05, 2003-05-06)              [2]
#> 2    15 R     [2003-04-20, 2003-06-20)              [2]
#> 3    16 M     [2001-01-02, 2002-03-04)              [1]
#> # … with 7 more rows

# Note how the total range of the splits vector matches the
# range of the corresponding interval
df$interval[[1]]
#> <iv<date>[1]>
#> [1] [2003-04-05, 2003-05-06)
df$splits[[1]]
#> <iv<date>[2]>
#> [1] [2003-04-05, 2003-04-20) [2003-04-20, 2003-05-06)

# From there we can unchop() the splits column so we can group on it
df <- df %>%
  unchop(splits)

# Note how rows 2 and 3 have the same `splits` value, so `E` and `R` will
# go together
df
#> # A tibble: 30 × 4
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>       ID char                  interval                   splits
#>    <int> <chr>               <iv<date>>               <iv<date>>
#>  1    15 E     [2003-04-05, 2003-05-06) [2003-04-05, 2003-04-20)
#>  2    15 E     [2003-04-05, 2003-05-06) [2003-04-20, 2003-05-06)
#>  3    15 R     [2003-04-20, 2003-06-20) [2003-04-20, 2003-05-06)
#>  4    15 R     [2003-04-20, 2003-06-20) [2003-05-06, 2003-06-20)
#>  5    16 M     [2001-01-02, 2002-03-04) [2001-01-02, 2002-03-04)
#>  6    17 I     [2003-03-05, 2007-02-22) [2003-03-05, 2005-04-15)
#>  7    17 I     [2003-03-05, 2007-02-22) [2005-04-15, 2007-02-22)
#>  8    17 C     [2005-04-15, 2014-05-19) [2005-04-15, 2007-02-22)
#>  9    17 C     [2005-04-15, 2014-05-19) [2007-02-22, 2007-05-15)
#> 10    17 C     [2005-04-15, 2014-05-19) [2007-05-15, 2008-02-05)
#> # … with 20 more rows

# Group by (ID, splits) and paste the `char` column elements together
df %>%
  group_by(ID, splits) %>%
  summarise(char = paste0(char, collapse = ","), .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 15 × 3
#>       ID                   splits char   
#>    <int>               <iv<date>> <chr>  
#>  1    15 [2003-04-05, 2003-04-20) E      
#>  2    15 [2003-04-20, 2003-05-06) E,R    
#>  3    15 [2003-05-06, 2003-06-20) R      
#>  4    16 [2001-01-02, 2002-03-04) M      
#>  5    17 [2003-03-05, 2005-04-15) I      
#>  6    17 [2005-04-15, 2007-02-22) I,C    
#>  7    17 [2007-02-22, 2007-05-15) C      
#>  8    17 [2007-05-15, 2008-02-05) C,I    
#>  9    17 [2008-02-05, 2010-06-07) C,M    
#> 10    17 [2010-06-07, 2010-09-22) C,M,V  
#> 11    17 [2010-09-22, 2011-02-14) C,M,V,P
#> 12    17 [2011-02-14, 2012-02-14) C,M,P  
#> 13    17 [2012-02-14, 2012-02-28) C,P    
#> 14    17 [2012-02-28, 2013-03-04) C,P,R  
#> 15    17 [2013-03-04, 2014-05-19) C,P
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>