# Find the duration of overlap between pairs of timestamps using data.table

Tags: r, datetime, data.table, overlap

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151452/find-overlapping-dates-for-each-id-and-create-a-new-row-for-the-overlap/46173303?noredirect=1#comment86774699_46173303), I'd like to find the duration of overlap between pairs of timestamps using `data.table`.

Here's my current code:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- fread(
  "stage,ID,date1,date2
  1,A,2018-04-17 00:00:00,2018-04-17 01:00:00
  1,B,2018-04-17 00:00:00,2018-04-17 00:20:00
  1,C,2018-04-17 00:15:00,2018-04-17 01:00:00
  2,B,2018-04-17 00:30:00,2018-04-17 01:10:00
  2,D,2018-04-17 00:30:00,2018-04-17 00:50:00",
  sep = ","
)

cols <- c("date1", "date2")
DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct), .SDcols = cols]

breaks <- DT[, {
  tmp <- unique(sort(c(date1, date2)))
  .(start = head(tmp, -1L), end = tail(tmp, -1L))
}, by = stage]

result <- DT[breaks, on = .(stage, date1 <= start, date2 >= end), paste(ID, collapse = "+"),  
    by = .EACHI, allow.cartesian = T] %>% 
  mutate(lengthinseconds = as.numeric(difftime(date2, date1, units = "secs")))
```

Which returns:

```
  stage               date1               date2    V1 lengthinseconds
1     1 2018-04-17 00:00:00 2018-04-17 00:15:00   B+A             900
2     1 2018-04-17 00:15:00 2018-04-17 00:20:00 B+A+C             300
3     1 2018-04-17 00:20:00 2018-04-17 01:00:00   A+C            2400
4     2 2018-04-17 00:30:00 2018-04-17 00:50:00   D+B            1200
5     2 2018-04-17 00:50:00 2018-04-17 01:10:00     B            1200
```

But I'd like to return only overlaps between user dyads (i.e. no more than two overlapping users). There are several hacky ways I can think of achieve this, such as:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

result %>% 
  filter(nchar(V1)==3) %>% 
  tidyr::separate(V1, c("ID1", "ID2"))
```

Which returns:

```
  stage               date1               date2 ID1 ID2 lengthinseconds
1     1 2018-04-17 00:00:00 2018-04-17 00:15:00   B   A             900
2     1 2018-04-17 00:20:00 2018-04-17 01:00:00   A   C            2400
3     2 2018-04-17 00:30:00 2018-04-17 00:50:00   D   B            1200
```

But this seems inelegant, especially when dealing with longer `ID` strings and potentially hundreds of `ID`s per overlap.

Ideally, I'd like to know if there's a way to modify the original `data.table` code to return this directly.

Comment: Btw, your title and first sentence mention duration but it seems unrelated to your output. Also, you might want to sort before pasting the IDs for more predictable output..

Comment: Good point, I've added the calculation of duration to my question. Yes I've been sorting the two columns `ID1` and `ID2` alphabetically within each row further downstream but seems easier to sort before the `paste` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance (and neglecting performance considerations), this requires only a minor modification to OP's code:

```
result <- DT[breaks, on = .(stage, date1 <= start, date2 >= end), 
             if (.N == 2L) paste(ID, collapse = "+"),  
             by = .EACHI, allow.cartesian = TRUE]
result
```

> ```
>    stage               date1               date2  V1
> 1:     1 2018-04-17 00:00:00 2018-04-17 00:15:00 B+A
> 2:     1 2018-04-17 00:20:00 2018-04-17 01:00:00 A+C
> 3:     2 2018-04-17 00:30:00 2018-04-17 00:50:00 D+B
> ```

Only for those groups, i.e., time ranges, where exactly two users are active a result row will be created.

---

The OP has requested to show the two `ID`s in separate columns plus to show the duration of the overlap. In addition, I suggest to have the `ID`s sorted.

```
result <- DT[breaks, on = .(stage, date1 <= start, date2 >= end), 
   if (.N == 2L) {
     tmp <- sort(ID)
     .(ID1 = tmp[1], ID2 = tmp[2], dur.in.sec = difftime(end, start, units = "secs"))
     },  
   by = .EACHI, allow.cartesian = TRUE]
result
```

> ```
>    stage               date1               date2 ID1 ID2 dur.in.sec
> 1:     1 2018-04-17 00:00:00 2018-04-17 00:15:00   A   B   900 secs
> 2:     1 2018-04-17 00:20:00 2018-04-17 01:00:00   A   C  2400 secs
> 3:     2 2018-04-17 00:30:00 2018-04-17 00:50:00   B   D  1200 secs
> ```

Comment: Thank @Uwe, this is great! Good motivation for me to learn more `data.table` and stop relying on only `dplyr` :)

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility:

```
DT[breaks, on = .(stage, date1 <= start, date2 >= end)
   ][, if (uniqueN(ID) == 2) .SD, by = .(stage, date1, date2)
     ][, dcast(.SD, stage + date1 + date2 ~ rowid(date1, prefix = 'ID'), value.var = 'ID')
       ][, lengthinseconds := as.numeric(difftime(date2, date1, units = "secs"))][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    stage               date1               date2 ID1 ID2 lengthinseconds
> 1:     1 2018-04-17 00:00:00 2018-04-17 00:15:00   B   A             900
> 2:     1 2018-04-17 00:20:00 2018-04-17 01:00:00   A   C            2400
> 3:     2 2018-04-17 00:30:00 2018-04-17 00:50:00   D   B            1200
> ```

Comment: Thank you @Jaap: it's useful to see other solutions to the same problem, plus an implementation of `dcast`. Seems to be plenty of ways to skin the cat using `data.table`!