# How to efficiently sort the characters in a string in R?

Tags: r, string, performance, sorting

How can I efficiently sort the characters of each string in a vector? For example, given a vector of strings:

```
set.seed(1)
strings <- c(do.call(paste0, replicate(4, sample(LETTERS, 10000, TRUE), FALSE)),
do.call(paste0, replicate(3, sample(LETTERS, 10000, TRUE), FALSE)),
do.call(paste0, replicate(2, sample(LETTERS, 10000, TRUE), FALSE)))
```

I have written a function that will split each string into a vector, sort the vector, and then collapse the output:

```
sort_cat <- function(strings){
  tmp <- strsplit(strings, split="")
  tmp <- lapply(tmp, sort)
  tmp <- lapply(tmp, paste0, collapse = "")
  tmp <- unlist(tmp)
  return(tmp)
}
sorted_strings <- sort_cat(strings)
```

However, the vector of strings I need to apply this to is very long, and this function is too slow. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to improve performance?

Comment: Check out the stringi package - it offers a speedup vs base. Rich Scriven's answer gives further details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904797/how-to-sort-letters-in-a-string

Comment: The `letters` are not always of length three as in your example, are they?

Comment: No, the length of the strings may vary.

Comment: I think that adding `fixed = TRUE` in `strsplit()` may improve the performance as it won't involve the use of regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce time by minimizing the number of loops for sure, and further do so by using the `parallel` package... my approach would be split strings once, then in the loop sort and paste:

```
sort_cat <- function(strings){
    tmp <- strsplit(strings, split="")
    tmp <- lapply(tmp, sort)
    tmp <- lapply(tmp, paste0, collapse = "")
    tmp <- unlist(tmp)
    return(tmp)
}

sort_cat2 <- function(strings){
    unlist(mcMap(function(i){
        stri_join(sort(i), collapse = "")
    }, stri_split_regex(strings, "|", omit_empty = TRUE, simplify = F), mc.cores = 8L))
}

> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
+     old = sort_cat(strings[1:500000]),
+     new = sort_cat2(strings[1:500000]),
+     times = 1
+ )
Unit: seconds
 expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
  old 9.62673395 9.62673395 9.62673395 9.62673395 9.62673395 9.62673395     1
  new 5.10547437 5.10547437 5.10547437 5.10547437 5.10547437 5.10547437     1
```

Shaves like 4 seconds, but it's still not that fast...

### Edit

Okay got it way down using `apply`.. strategy here:

1)  extract letters rather than split boundaries
2)  create a matrix with the results
3)  iterate through row-wise
4)  Sort
5) Join

You avoid multiple loops and unlisting.... IGNORE: <strike>?caveat is if strings different lengths, you'll need to remove any empty or NA within the `apply` such as `i[!is.na(i) && nchar(i) > 0]`</strike>

```
sort_cat3 <- function(strings){
    apply(stri_extract_all_regex(strings, "\\p{L}", simplify = TRUE), 1, function(i){
        stri_join(stri_sort(i), collapse = "")
    })
}

> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
+     old = sort_cat(strings[1:500000]),
+     mapping = sort_cat2(strings[1:500000]),
+     applying = sort_cat3(strings[1:500000]),
+     times = 1
+ )
Unit: seconds
     expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
      old 10.35101934 10.35101934 10.35101934 10.35101934 10.35101934 10.35101934     1
  mapping  5.12771799  5.12771799  5.12771799  5.12771799  5.12771799  5.12771799     1
 applying  3.97775326  3.97775326  3.97775326  3.97775326  3.97775326  3.97775326     1
```

Takes us from 10.3 secs to 3.98

Comment: What is the speedup if you run the original function in parallel?

Comment: brought down by a little over 50%. 


`tmp <- strsplit(strings, split="")
    unlist(mclapply(tmp, function(i){
        paste0(sort(i), collapse = "")
    }))`

Comment: @Gregor it does. Just tested and appears to?

Comment: Cool, just checking :)

Comment: No not at all.. totally had the same question myself.. which means omit the note i put in the answer regarding removing NA/empty... don't need it. `stringi` is my favorite package by far man...

Answer (score 4):

Re-implementing using `stringi` gives a roughly 4x speedup. I also edited `sort_cat` to use `fixed = TRUE` in the `strsplit`, which makes it a *little* faster. And thanks to Carl for the single loop suggestion, which speeds us up just a little bit more.

```
sort_cat <- function(strings){
  tmp <- strsplit(strings, split="", fixed = TRUE)
  tmp <- lapply(tmp, sort)
  tmp <- lapply(tmp, paste0, collapse = "")
  tmp <- unlist(tmp)
  return(tmp)
}

library(stringi)
sort_stringi = function(s) {
  s = stri_split_boundaries(s, type = "character")
  s = lapply(s, stri_sort)
  s = lapply(s, stri_join, collapse = "")
  unlist(s)
}

sort_stringi_loop = function(s) {
  s = stri_split_boundaries(s, type = "character")
  for (i in seq_along(s)) {
    s[[i]] = stri_join(stri_sort(s[[i]]), collapse = "")
  }
  unlist(s)
}

bench::mark(
  sort_cat(strings),
  sort_stringi(strings),
  sort_stringi_loop(strings)
)
# # A tibble: 3 x 13
#   expression                    min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory
#   <bch:expr>                 <bch:> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>
# 1 sort_cat(strings)          23.01s 23.01s    0.0435    31.2MB     2.17     1    50     23.01s <chr ~ <Rpro~
# 2 sort_stringi(strings)       6.16s  6.16s    0.162     30.5MB     2.11     1    13      6.16s <chr ~ <Rpro~
# 3 sort_stringi_loop(strings)  5.75s  5.75s    0.174     15.3MB     1.74     1    10      5.75s <chr ~ <Rpro~
# # ... with 2 more variables: time <list>, gc <list>
```

This method could also be used in parallel. Profiling the code to see which operations actually take the longest would be a good next step if you want to go even faster.

Comment: I think this will end up faster than apply and not rely on removing empty values if different lengths. might suggest one loop wrapped in unlist, though?

Comment: Single loop improves speed just a little bit more, thanks!

Comment: yea man. this is still bugging me, though. I feel like im missing a very obvious and easier way to do this whole thing....

Comment: I mean, it would probably be pretty easy to write an RCPP function that just does this and would be lightning fast. But working within R, I think we're limited to basically doing these steps.

Comment: that's what I was thinkin: C++

Answer (score 1):

This version is slightly faster

```
sort_cat2=function(strings){
A=matrix(unlist(strsplit(strings,split="")),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
B=t(apply(A,1,sort))
paste0(B[,1],B[,2],B[,3])
}
```

But I think it might be optimized

Comment: Will only work if the length of all the strings is the same. Nice and quick, though!