# How can I find all the possible combinations of elements in column vector and cross check them from another dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have  2 data frames of a single column

data frame A:

| var |
| --- |
| A |
| B |

and data frame B:

| var |
| --- |
| A |
| C |

```
library(tidyverse) 
A = tibble(var = c("A","B"))
B = tibble(var = c("A","C"))
```

I want to find all the possible combinations of the elements in the var column in a new data frame that must look like this :

| varA | varB |
| --- | --- |
| A | A |
| A | B |
| A | C |
| B | C |

Now from this resulted data frame I want to find this combinations in another data frame no matter the position (first or second,varA - varB) of the new data frame and give me the column y with the corresponded values.

| varA | varB | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | A | 1.12 |
| A | A | 1.14 |
| C | A | 1.15 |
| B | C | 1.16 |
| D | F | 1.23 |
| H | G | 1.1 |

```
D = tibble(varA = c("B","A","C","B","D","H"),
           varB = c("A","A","A","C","F","G"),
           y = c(1.12,1.14,1.15,1.16,1.23,1.10));D
```

ideally I want to look like this :

| varA | varB | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | 1.14 |
| A | B | 1.12 |
| A | C | 1.15 |
| B | C | 1.16 |

How can I do this in R using dplyr package or base functions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempt.

```
library(tidyverse) 
A = tibble(var = c("A","B"))
B = tibble(var = c("A","C"))

# create data frame of all combinations 
B <- expand.grid(A$var, B$var)

D <- tibble(varA = c("B","A","C","B","D","H"),
            varB = c("A","A","A","C","F","G"),
            y = c(1.12,1.14,1.15,1.16,1.23,1.10));D

# create new column and sort 

strSort <- function(x)
  sapply(lapply(strsplit(x, NULL), sort), paste, collapse = "")

D <- D %>% mutate(var_new = strSort(paste(varA, varB)))
B <- B %>% mutate(var_new = strSort(paste(Var1, Var2)))


left_join(B, D) %>% select(Var1, Var2, y)
```

I use expand.grid to create all possible combination, and then I create a new column for both data frames with the sorted string ([sorting function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904797/how-to-sort-letters-in-a-string)), to make sure the order does not matter, then it is a simple left join and cleaning the resulting data frame.